# El click en un botón no hace nada en Action Bar Tabs en Android

Tags: android

Estoy trabajando con en un proyecto con Action Bar Tabs en Android. He logrado crear mis fragments y lograr la interacción deseada, pero tengo un problema. En uno de esos fragments tengo un button, pero al darle click no hace nada.

Este en el código que uso para llamar al fragment desde el MainActivity:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView=null;
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frm_dispositivos, container, false);
                //return rootView;
            break;
            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frm_transaccion, container, false);
                //return rootView;
            break;
            case 3:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frm_cajero, container, false);
                //return rootView;
            break;
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

y este es lo que hago en  el fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frm_cajero, container, false);
    btnGuardar=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarCajero);
    btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"no sirve",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no estás cargando el `fragment` simplemente estas haciendo un `inflate` de vistas en el `MainActivy`, solo tienes una vista cargada en la pantalla no el `fragment`, si lo que deseas es cambiar el `fragment` desde el `MainActivity` debes hacer un [FragmentTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) :

**MainActivity:**

```
public View onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           Fragment newFragment = null;
           FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)){
                case 1:
                  newFragment = New FragmentDispositivos();
                break;
                case 2:
                  newFragment = New FragmentTransaccion();
                break;
                case 3:
                  newFragment = New FragmentCajero();
                break;
            }
            // Debes pasar el contenedor donde tienes el fragment y lo 
            // reemplaza por el nuevo fragment
             transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
             transaction.addToBackStack(null);

           // Commit de la transaction
           transaction.commit();
        }
    }
```